# InnoDB locking a different index while using a where clause on a foreign key

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking, mariadb, innodb

I'm trying these queries in two different transactions:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM `StopHistory` WHERE `deviceId` = 34;

START TRANSACTION;
SELECT id FROM `StopHistory` WHERE deviceId = 33 AND endAt > '2018-06-18 17:01:32.473';
```

the second query waits, since the first query is creating a lock on the endAt field.

```
MySQL [(none)]> select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_LOCKS;
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+
| lock_id               | lock_trx_id | lock_mode | lock_type | lock_table               | lock_index | lock_space | lock_page | lock_rec | lock_data                |
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+
| 104222007:699:1035:16 | 104222007   | S         | RECORD    | `db`.`StopHistory`       | endAt      |        641 |      1035 |       16 | 0x99A026D21307DA, 115347 |
| 104221958:699:1035:16 | 104221958   | X         | RECORD    | `db`.`StopHistory`       | endAt      |        641 |      1035 |       16 | 0x99A026D21307DA, 115347 |
+-----------------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------------------------+------------+------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------+

    ---TRANSACTION 104231466, ACTIVE 3 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 4 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 3 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 59556, OS thread handle 0x2b1375f03700, query id 20584248 172.31.2.181 db Sending data
SELECT id FROM `StopHistory` WHERE deviceId = 33 AND endAt > '2018-06-18 17:01:32.473'
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 3 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 641 page no 1035 n bits 16 index `endAt` of table `db`.`StopHistory` trx id 104231466 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 16 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len=7; bufptr=0x2b134db1c16c; hex= 99a026d21307da; asc   &    ;;
 1: len=4; bufptr=0x2b134db1c173; hex= 8001c293; asc     ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 104231429, ACTIVE 11 sec
44 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 3103 row lock(s), undo log entries 1549
MySQL thread id 59555, OS thread handle 0x2b1375f03700, query id 20584210 172.31.2.181 db delayed send ok done
```

the `StopHistory` table has a foreign key on deviceId and an index on endAt

```
CREATE TABLE `StopHistory` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `endAt` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deviceId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `beginAt` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_StopHystory_2_idx` (`deviceId`),
  KEY `beginAt` (`beginAt`),
  KEY `endAt` (`endAt`),
  KEY `device_beginAt` (`deviceId`,`beginAt`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_StopHystory_2` FOREIGN KEY (`deviceId`) REFERENCES `Devices` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=115351 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

output of the explain:

```
MySQL [db]> explain DELETE FROM `StopHistory` WHERE `deviceId` = 34 \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: StopHistory
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,fk_StopHystory_1_idx,fk_StopHystory_2_idx,fk_StopHistory_1_idx,beginAt,endAt,device_beginAt
          key: fk_StopHystory_2_idx
      key_len: 5
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1548
        Extra: Using where
```

Why the endAt field is locked?

Comment: My geuss the delete didn't affected foreign key relationships changes so InnoDB engine didn't lock the foreign key index records to keep the performance and accessibility of all foreign key relationships records to the max for other queries... So a DELETE from the Devices table should lock the foreign key index record(s)

Answer (score 0):

To help with that `SELECT`, and possibly cut down the chance of lock, change

```
KEY `fk_StopHystory_2_idx` (`deviceId`),
```

To

```
KEY(deviceId, endAt)
```

Also, note that 34 comes right after 33.  So deleting all the 34s is touching the "gap" after the 33s.  This may be an unavoidable cause for lock contention.

Also note that the `DELETE` needs to remove items from 3 BTrees -- the main one, plus both indexes starting with `deviceId`.  Presumably the latter two will go through the "Change Buffer" and not be too critical.